# multiple where and or condition in Laravel

Tags: laravel

How can I prepare the query condition about multiple where condition.
I need to retrieve the records relating to the current year and month for the dataIT (start) and dataFT (end) relating to a name (cognome is lastname and nome is name)
Considering that it must be valid for example dates starting and ending at the works of the current month:
dataIT = 2021-04-30 and dataFT = 2021-05-01
or
dataIT = 2021-05-10 and dataFT = 2021-06-10

```
    $result=DB::table('timbraturas')
            ->where('cognome',$cognome)
            ->where('nome',$nome)
            ->whereMonth('dataIT','=',Carbon::now()->month)
            ->whereYear('dataIT','=',Carbon::now()->year)

             **or (
                  ->whereYear('dataFT','=',Carbon::now()->year)
                  ->whereMonth('dataFT','=',Carbon::now()->month)
              )**

            ->orderBy('id','asc')
            ->get();
    return $result;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A closure can be used with the `orWhere` option, this allows specifying multiple conditions.

```
 $result=DB::table('timbraturas')
            ->where('cognome',$cognome)
            ->where('nome',$nome)
            ->whereMonth('dataIT','=',Carbon::now()->month)
            ->whereYear('dataIT','=',Carbon::now()->year)
            ->orWhere(function($query) {
                  $query->whereYear('dataFT','=',Carbon::now()->year)
                  ->whereMonth('dataFT','=',Carbon::now()->month);
              })
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#or-where-clauses

Comment: Great! Could you accept/update the answer so others can find it?

Comment: how can I do? sorry but I'm a beginner and I did not understand

Comment: There is a checkmark that you can click under the arrows on the left side of the answer. Checkout the docs: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I just tested the solution better, I noticed that I get the values of all users (surname and name) surname and name.